# loading many UIWebviews triggers a memory peak on ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiwebview, rubymotion

I am working on an app that needs to load many uiwebviews (about 50 or more) on a single 
view controller (the second one on the whole app)  in order to pre render them . the problem is that creating these webviews and loading the html with js generates a huge peak of memory reaching about 200 MB  which obviously sometimes makes the app to crash.

I need to pass an array with these webviews already loaded across the next view controllers and I can only get rid of them after all of them are shown.

I already found a vendor to clear properly webviews , cleanWebViewDealloc and also set the link detection to off but it is still not enough.

Note that the cycle is repeated continuously.So is there another way to improve this condition? Is there something else that I am not doing or that I could do ?

PD : Im working  with rubymotion and some vendors.

Comment: Are you sure your approach to your particular problem is the best? Putting 50 web views on a single screen seems like a bad idea to me. What are you loading in those views? Can't you just put them in one single web view (maybe using html frames)?

Comment: Are you trying to load them all asynch at the same time? Can you load them synchronously in series instead, or maybe only have 3-4 loading at any one time?

Comment: I'm loading some html with Mathjax scripts embedded that I receive from a webservice,I have to execute all the MathJax rendering and the show each webview (already rendered) on a different view controller.Im passing an array with the webviews and showing them one by one.(It is required to have all the webview rendered already)

Comment: Any chance you can adopt a 'just-in-time' strategy for those webviews? I hope that you aren't showing 50 at a time. Random thoughts: could you pre-render a webview, then store the content and get it out of memory. Read and display when necessary. If you have 50 webviews, keep the current one plus maybe 2 or 3 previous and subsequent webviews loaded. Something akin to what a standard tableview does when married to an NSFetchedResultsController, and reusable cells. There's got to be a way to reduce you 'active' memory load, it's just going to take some work.